# determine if the given vectors span $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, span

Determine if the given vectors span $\mathbb{R}^4$

${(1, 1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0, 1)}$.

I'm completely confused on this question. My textbook gives a different problem but in $\mathbb{R}^3$. How would i go about this?

Comment: You could use row reductions to find a different set of vectors that span the same space.

Comment: You need to know that all four vectors are linearly independent. One way to check this is to show that the determinant of the 4x4 matrix formed by these vectors is non-zero.

Comment: You solve the problem exactly like you would solve the 3x3 problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find constants $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ such that every vector $(x,y,z,w) \in \mathbb{R}^4$ can be written as a linear combination of the given vectors. That is, \begin{align}(x,y,z,w)&=a(1,1,1,1)+b(0,1,1,1)+c(0,0,1,1)+d(0,0,0,1)\\
&=(a,a+b,a+b+c,a+b+c+d).
\end{align}
Equating components, we have: $$x=a, \quad y=a+b, \quad z=a+b+c, \quad w=a+b+c+d.$$

Hence, $$a=x, \quad b=y-x, \quad c=z-y, \quad d=w-z.$$

Therefore, the given list of vectors spans $\mathbb{R}^4$ (since the vector $(x,y,z,w)$ was arbitrary).

Alternatively, you can check to see that the given vectors are linearly independent, and then, since there are $\dim(\mathbb{R}^4)=4$ of them, they must be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$. They therefore span $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Arrange the vectors as rows of a matrix.
2. Compute the determinant. It is particularly easy to compute as the matrix is upper triangular, so the determinant is just the product of the diagonal entries. It is equal to $1$.
3. Conclude that the rows of the matrix are linearly independent.
4. Any Four linearly independent vectors span $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Answer (score 0):

Not needed any sophisticated knowledge, just a simple understanding: the most right vector gives 1 dimension,
2nd rightmost 2nd dimension, 2nd left 3rd dimension and first one 4th dimension.
If you do not believe, subtract two consetive vectors - and get the standard basis exactly.